# How to use after_create callback with MongoMapper Embedded Document?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, callback, sinatra, mongomapper

According to the [documentation](http://mongomapper.com/documentation/documents/embedded-document.html), Embedded Documents are created with `new`:

```
Order.create(:line_items => [
  LineItem.new(:name => 'Undershirt', :quantity => 5),
  LineItem.new(:name => 'Underwear',  :quantity => 2)
])
```

But this does not trigger the `LineItem.after_create` callback. (It does, however, trigger the `Order.after_create` callback.)

Changing `new` to `create` fails because there is no `save` method for an Embedded Document.

So, how to use `after_create` or `after_initialize` ([which doesn't seem to exist](http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/callbacks.html))?

Is there another/better way to implement a callback or Observer Pattern?

Working in Sinatra.